# Python-Scikit. Training and testing data using SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am working on training and testing of data using SVM (scikit). I am training SVM and preparing a pickle from it. Then, I am using that pickle to test my system. First I am reading the training data and testing data in variables `train_data` and `test_data` respectively.

After that, the code I am using for training is:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df = 0.8,
                             sublinear_tf=True,
                             use_idf=True)
train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_data)

classifier_rbf = svm.SVC()
classifier_rbf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(classifier_rbf, 'pickl/train_rbf_SVM.pkl',1)
```

Again while testing, I am reading the training data and testing data in variables `train_data` and `test_data` respectively. The code I am using for testing is:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df = 0.8,
                             sublinear_tf=True,
                             use_idf=True)
train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
classifier_rbf = joblib.load('pickl/train_rbf_SVM.pkl')
prediction_rbf = classifier_rbf.predict(test_vectors)
```

This code is working fine and giving me correct output. My question is - is it compulsory to read training data whenever I want to do testing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, yes.
Because you are not saving (pickling)  the `tfidfVectorizer`. 
The test data must be transformed in the exact same way as the train data is transformed to give any meanungful predictions. 
So, if you want to not read train data again and again, pickle the `tfidfVectorizer` too along with some estimator and unpicke it during testing.

Also you may want to look at the **Pipeline** provided in scikit-learn to combine data pre processing and estimating into one object which you can pickle and unpicke easily without having to worry about pickling and loading various parts of the training

**Edit - Added code**

While training for the first time, add this line to your code in the end:

```
joblib.dump(vectorizer, 'pickl/train_vectorizer.pkl',1)
```

Now when testing on the data, no need to load training data. Just load the already fitted vectorizer:

```
classifier_rbf = joblib.load('pickl/train_rbf_SVM.pkl')
vectorizer = joblib.load('pickl/train_vectorizer.pkl')

test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
prediction_rbf = classifier_rbf.predict(test_vectors)
```

Comment: I pickled my `train_vector` as well as `train_labels`. Even then, if I removed line with call to `fit_transform`, it gives me error that vocabulary doesn't fitted.

Comment: Trainvector and trainlabels doest matter.. What you should pickle is the vectorizer and classifier_rbf

Comment: That is what I did in code shown in my question. Can you plz write the code in your answer for me. Thank you.

Comment: No, in your code you are not pickling the `vectorizer`. I have changed the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: Done! Worked as I was expected.