# Dealing With Variations In Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am working on a text data structuring.

I need to make predictions using the following format:

> xyz@gmail.com -> Email, India -> Country, etc....

To achieve that, `SVC` along with `OneVsRestClassifier` is being used. The data extrapolation works just fine if the **train** and **test** subsets are in the same script.

However, the predictioning fails if evaluating separately, i.e. **train** and **test** data are in separate *Python* scripts).

The error I receive points to the **variations in the sparse matrix dimensions**.

help me kindly to resolve this variation issue.

---

#### Sample Trainer Module

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

#Tfidf vectorizer for text data

tfidf_enc = TfidfVectorizer(binary=True)
lbl_enc = LabelEncoder()

X = tfidf_enc.fit_transform(name_text)
X = X.astype('float16')

y = lbl_enc.fit_transform(name_label)
clf = SVC(C=100, kernel='rbf', degree=3,
          gamma=1, coef0=1, shrinking=True, 
          probability=True, tol=0.001, cache_size=200,
          class_weight=None, verbose=2, max_iter=-1,
          decision_function_shape=None, random_state=None) 
model = OneVsRestClassifier(clf, n_jobs=4)
model.fit(X,y)

import pickle
# save the model to disk
filename = 'D:/authAff_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

#### Sample Testing Module

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pickle
# load the model from disk
filename = 'D:/authAff_model.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

#Prediction
test_as_text = ['France','xyz@gmail.com','Singapore']
test_as_text = [item.lower() for item in test_as_text]

tfidf_enc = TfidfVectorizer(binary=True)

X_test = tfidf_enc.fit_transform(test_as_text)
X_test = X_test.astype('float16')
y_test = loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

#### Error Message

When testing as a separate script the following error occurs:

> ValueError: X.shape[1] = 6 should be equal to 6104, the number of features at training time

Original dimensionality:

```
<3x6104 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float16'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-Scikit. Training and testing data using SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029956/python-scikit-training-and-testing-data-using-svm)

Comment: See the above question which describes the same problem and almost same answer by me. Just using the `joblib` instead of pickle because its the [recommended way](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) for scikit. The error is you are using different TfidfVectorizers for training and testing. Save the original `TfidfVectorizer` with the model and load in testing module and only call `X_test = loaded_tfidf.transform(test_as_text)`, not `fit_transform()`.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thank you so much your guidance :-)